# 'Assembly uses xxx which has a higher version' vs 'Could not load file or assembly'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a .NET application that has a number of references. Many of those references have their own dependencies.

In other words, there is an application `A` that depends on application `B`, which, in turns, references assembly `C`. There is also a dependency on `D` that relies on `E`.

So, if I want to use a different version of `C`. I just reference that different version in my `.csproj` of `A`. I obviously get a runtime exception of `Could not load file or assembly... The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference`. I easily solve that problem by using `BindingRedirect`.

However, if I'm trying to use a different version of `E`, I instead get a compilation error saying that `'Assembly uses xxx which has a higher version of yyy`. And that compilation error cannot be solved by the runtime directive `bindingRedirect`.

Both 'B' and 'D' are strongly named assemblies. And there are no noticable differences between the way they are built.

Why in one case I receive a runtime exception (solvable by `bindingRedirect`) and a compilation error in another?

Comment: I don't have a full solution, but to answer your very last line, dependencies have version requirements that are checked at build time, whereas it isn't until it tries to actually use the reference that you get an error because it doesn't match the version that was in the assembly's reference.

Comment: Is it always the case that an assembly's references are checked at a build time?

Comment: Hmm, you are missing something.  There must be another project that depends on E.  And D probably exposes types from E.

Comment: It is not clear what you are tying to achieve. You application depends on E and D. D in turns depends on E and you want to use a different version of E just for your application?

Comment: xxx needs to be upgraded, one of your DLLs is using a newer version. Then use binding redirects for those libraries built to run against older versions of xxx.

Answer (score -1):

I've conducted a few experiments using test projects and found the cause of the issue.

The original problem was that there was a project A that was dependent on:

```
B using C
D using E
```

I was able to update (downgrade) `C` and still use build `A`, while I couldn't do the same of `E`.

I was getting an error `Assembly uses E which has a higher version of yyy` occurs attempting to build the project.

As it turns out the error occurs when it's not possible to build `D` with that particular version of `E` because, for example, of changes in one of the interfaces.